# Solving first order linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

With a chemical reaction $A + 2B → 3C$, concentrations $a (t)$, $b (t)$ and
$c (t)$ of the three substances A, B and C in the differential equations satisfy:

1. $ \frac {da} {dt} = -rab^2$
2. $\frac{db}{dt} = −2rab^2$
3. $\frac{dc}{dt} = 3rab^2$

Show that for every $t$, $b (t) - 2a (t) = 0$ and $c (t) + 3a (t) = 3$?

I never studied about this kind differential equations nor i find any source anywhere, how do i solve this?

Comment: You are not asked to solve the equations. Just manipulate the expressions you are given and see under which conditions they are satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to actually solve the DE's.

Notice that
$$2a'=b'$$
So
$$b'-2a'=0$$
Integrating with appropriate boundary conditions,
$$b-2a=0$$

Same goes for the second equation, since $$c'+3a'=0$$